# error define a template haskell function

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am beginning to learn Template haskell, so I want create a function that receive a String param that define the name to the function to generate

```
build_p5 :: String -> [Dec]
build_p5 name =
[ FunD p1 
         [ Clause [TupP [VarP a,VarP b]] (NormalB (AppE (VarE c) (VarE a))) [FunD c [Clause [VarP a] (NormalB (VarE a)) []]]
         ]
] where
   p1 = mkName name
   a = mkName "a"
   b = mkName "b"
   c = mkName "ident"
```

to run the definition :

```
$(build_p5 "hola")
```

but when I run the program get the following error

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘[Dec]’ with ‘Q [Dec]’
> Expected type: DecsQ
>   Actual type: [Dec]
> In the expression: build_p5 "hola"
> ```

correct code

```
build_p2 :: Monad m => String -> m [Dec]
build_p2 name =
return [ FunD p1 
     [ Clause [TupP [VarP a,VarP b]] (NormalB (AppE (VarE c) (VarE a))) [FunD c [Clause [VarP a] (NormalB (VarE a)) []]]
     ]
  ] where
  p1 = mkName name
  a = mkName "a"
  b = mkName "b"
  c = mkName "ident"
```

Comment: You have to have your template haskell function return a `Q [Dec]`, and since `Q` is a `Monad` you should be able to just `return [FunD p1 ...]` in your function definition.  Does that work for what you want to do?

Comment: thank you it work add the code corrected in the answers, i create this method only to exercise, the idea is that you can define the name to the function as a parameter

Comment: add the code corrected